# Отображение виджетов в менеджере компоновки QGridLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qlabel, qgridlayout

Нужно чтобы между объектами компоновки `QGridLayout` отображалась граница:

```
import random
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QLabel, QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
class TikTakToe(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TikTakToe, self).__init__()
        grd = QGridLayout()
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                grd.addWidget(QLabel(random.choice(['x', 'o'])), i, j)
        self.setLayout(grd)
        self.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())

ttt = TikTakToe()
```

---

Результат выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а нужно чтобы было что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лучше всего для меня будет предусмотренный метод самого менеджера компоновки, если такой есть. Или что-то другое, не слишком многострочное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В цикле, при добавлении `QLabel` добавьте параметр

`QLabel.setStyleSheet('border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black;')`

Должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

**Добавление границ элементов:**

```
label = QLabel(random.choice(['x', 'o']))
label.setStyleSheet('border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black;')
grd.addWidget(label, i, j)
```

**Увеличение шрифта:**

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont 
label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 26, QFont.Bold))
```

**Убираем расстояние между элементами:**

```
grd.setSpacing(0)
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Мне показалось, что вам вместо `QLabel` больше подойдет виджет `QPushButton`

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QLabel, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class TikTakToe(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TikTakToe, self).__init__()
        
        grd = QGridLayout(self)
        grd.setSpacing(0)
        
        for i in range(1,4):
            for j in range(1,4):
#                grd.addWidget(QLabel(random.choice(['x', 'o'])), i, j)
                btn = QPushButton(random.choice(['x', 'o']))
                btn.setFixedSize(60, 60)
                btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, text=btn.text(): self.onClick(text))
                grd.addWidget(btn, i, j)
                
        grd.setColumnStretch(0, 1) 
        grd.setColumnStretch(4, 1)
        grd.setRowStretch(0, 1) 
        grd.setRowStretch(4, 1)
       
    def onClick(self, text):
        print(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    app.setFont(QFont('Arial', 26, QFont.Bold))
    w = TikTakToe()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]